# Update table based on multiple conditions without using CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I need to update a table based on multiple conditions and the update needs to be done in one update statement. In addition, the restriction is that I CANNOT use the following construct due to performance issues since there are about 18 CASE expressions in my update:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.col1 = CASE WHEN B.col = someValue      THEN B.Col2 END,
    B.Col2 = CASE WHEN b.col = someOtherValue THEN B.Col2 END,
    .
    .
    --18th CASE stmt
    B.Col18 = CASE WHEN b.col = YetAnotherValue THEN B.Col2 END
FROM
    tableA A 
INNER JOIN
    tableB B ON A.someColumn = B.someColumn
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated .

Comment: Update statements have different dialectics depending on the DBMS. So, please also tag your DBMS.

Comment: `CASE` **expressions** (not statements!) in an update shouldn't be much of a performance issue. Do you have indexes on `tablea.somecolumn` and `tableb.somecolumn`?

Comment: T-SQL (MSFT SQL Server)

Comment: I have an index on tableA. Regarding tableB, there are multiple records with same unique identifiers and other fields  and therefore uniqueness of records is not present and therefore I am unable to create index based on my limited index knowledge.

Comment: why do you feel there will be a performance problem, with 18 case expressions?.

Comment: A column (set) doesn't need to be a key (only have unique values) to place an index on it.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph, senior developer looked at the code and said performance will be compromised with 18 updates (as in the example in the code I posted).

Comment: @brand_new_developer its a single update statement and so it shouldnt matter. If you were doing this in a loop i would reconsider writing this. Try to benchmark the performance, Are you going to update millions or records with this update

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph Definitely no looping. Approximately 250,000 records will be updated. By benchmarking performance do you mean looking at execution plan?

Comment: You can load a similar volume of data in your lower enviornment -DEV and run the update to see how long its going to take. Since this is a single sql statement it shouldnt take long. tip: if it does then drop then indexes --> run the update --> re create the index, this should reduce the time

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you actually want to aggregate *before* updating:

```
UPDATE A
    SET A.col1 = B.col1,
        B.Col2 = B.col2,
          . . .
    FROM tableA A JOIN
         (SELECT B.someColumn,
                 MAX(CASE WHEN B.col = someValue THEN B.Col2 END) as col1,
                 MAX(CASE WHEN b.col = someOtherValue THEN B.Col2 END) as col2,
                 . . .
          FROM tableB B
          GROUP BY B.someColumn
         ) B
         ON A.someColumn = B.someColumn
```